# Dynamic table_name and nextval_sequence_name in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, tablename, nextval

I need a way to create table and nextval sequence name dynamically in PostgreSQL, can this be done without brain meltdown?

My thinking goes along the lines of:

```
DECLARE
    $tablename varchar(50) = "name_of_table";

-- Sequence and defined type
CREATE SEQUENCE IF NOT EXISTS $tablename_id_seq; <-- PROBABLY NEED SOME SORT OF CONCATENATION HERE

-- Table Definition
CREATE TABLE $tablename (
    "id" int4 NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval($tablename || '_id_seq'::regclass),

 ... (the rest omitted)
```

What I'm trying to achieve: I'm building an interface where a user can type in the name of the table they'd like to create, and based on the input of that field a table of that name with matching sequence is created ...

Comment: Dynamic SQL, so brain meltdown cannot be avoided. Sorry.

Comment: What is the actual problem you try to solve? Why would you even create a sequence, when the database can do this automatically ? Use an identity column. This also avoids the future problems with permissions and ownership.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, and it's [built-in](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html#SQL-CREATETABLE-PARMS-GENERATED-IDENTITY). There are [`smallserial`,`serial` and `bigserial`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/16/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL) types that do exactly that:

```sql
CREATE TABLE $tablename (
    "id" serial NOT NULL);
```

And there's ([better](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_serial)) [identity column](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html#SQL-CREATETABLE-PARMS-GENERATED-IDENTITY) syntax [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77570415/dynamic-table-name-and-nextval-sequence-name-in-postgresql/77570831#comment136752382_77570415) by [@Frank Heikens](https://stackoverflow.com/users/271959/frank-heikens) above

```sql
CREATE TABLE tablename (
    "id" int4 generated by default as identity NOT NULL);
```

Then, if you want the sequence, you can use [`pg_get_serial_sequence()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-info.html#id-1.5.8.32.6.3.2.2.15.1.1.1).

```
insert into tablename values(default),(default),(default) returning *;
```

| id |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |

```
select pg_get_serial_sequence('tablename','id'),
       currval(pg_get_serial_sequence('tablename','id'));
```

| pg_get_serial_sequence | currval |
| --- | --- |
| public.tablename_id_seq | 3 |

If you decide to keep creating these by hand, make sure to later [link](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-altersequence.html#id-1.9.3.30.6) them to the column they are responsible for:

```sql
alter sequence my_seq owned by my_table.my_column;
```

---

If you're asking about dynamic SQL syntax in general, not just sequence name dynamically generated based on table name, there are examples [in the doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN):

```
DO $r$
DECLARE my_table_name text:='my_table_'||(random()*1000)::int;
BEGIN
EXECUTE FORMAT ('CREATE TABLE %1$I ("id" generated by default as identity NOT NULL);',my_table_name);
END $r$;

select tablename, 
       pg_get_serial_sequence(tablename,'id'),
       nextval(pg_get_serial_sequence(tablename,'id'))
from pg_tables where tablename ilike '%my_table_%';
```

| tablename | pg_get_serial_sequence | nextval |
| --- | --- | --- |
| my_table_25 | public.my_table_25_id_seq | 1 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/qfdzFtbe)

Comment: I don't get WHERE this is dynamic? I see strings 'tablename' ... how is that dynamic?

Comment: But I WANT a dynamically created table (tablename). WHERE in your example is your table name dynamic? I can only see it as this will create a table named "$tablename" not 'contracts' for instance.

Comment: The sequence name is dynamically generated based on the name of the table it's responsible for. If you're asking about running dynamic sql in general, I added an example of that in an update. Addressing your question edit, you only need to create the table this way and the sequence name will automatically follow as long as you use `serial` type or identity column.

Comment: I do get that the sequence is automagically generated ... but I'm interested in the TABLE_NAME as being set through a VARIABLE. All I can find is DECLARE, but that seems to be part of PL/pgSQL which is NOT SQL as I understand it.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I'm looking for ...

Comment: Plain SQL doesn't offer that, not on the language level. You need PL/pgSQL as shown above, or you need to dynamically construct your plain SQL queries using any other language, and substitute the object names from variables the exact same way PL/pgSQL would. That being said, there's no need to handle the sequence separately, you only need to handle the table.

Comment: Don't use a serial: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_serial